# What is the difference between Qiskit execute and the IBMQJobManager?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I was researching how to submit multiple pulse schedules/circuits in the same job and came across 2 methods:

1. Executing Experiments with [`qiskit.execute`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/execute.html)
2. and [`IBMQJobManager.run`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.IBMQJobManager.run.html)

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using either over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`qiskit.execute` is a convenience function that does both `transpile` and `assemble` under the cover.

`IBMQJobManager.run` does *not* do `transpile`, but it does `assemble`. `IBMQJobManager` will, however, split your schedules/circuits into multiple jobs, submit them, and consolidate the results if the number of schedules/circuits exceed the maximum allowed for a backend per job. `qiskit.execute` doesn't do this and the job will just fail the limit is reached.